# Is there a way to specify arbitrary extras in a Python TypedDict?

Tags: python, mypy, typing, pylance, pyright

I would like to specify a `TypedDict` that specifies some fields and types, but also allows for having a "bag" of extra things that are allowed in the dict.

A concrete example of this would be for adding typing information to a decorator that would be used in conjunction with Flask (since, if I'm not mistaken, the flask `route` decorator passes the "path params" as keyword arguments. I would like to be able to access a `kwarg`, manipulate it, and pass it along.

My decorator might look more or less like this:

```py
from typing import Any, Callable, ParamSpec, Tuple, TypedDict, TypeVar

from myproject.models import Thing

P0 = ParamSpec("P0")
P1 = ParamSpec("P1")
R = TypeVar("R")

# I know these TypedDicts aren't valid, but hopefully they illustrate what I want.
class IncomingKwargs(TypedDict):
    thing_id: str
    **rest


class ForwardedKwargs(TypedDict):
    thing: Thing
    **rest


Decoratee = Callable[P0, R]
Decorated = Callable[P1, R]


# Take the following with a grain of salt...
def with_thing() -> Callable[[Decoratee], Decorated]:
    def decorator(f: Decoratee) -> Decorated:
        def wrapper(*args: Any, **kwargs: IncomingKwargs) -> R
            # Example manipulation.
            thing = Thing.from_id(kwargs["thing_id"])   
            return f(*args, thing=thing, **kwargs["rest"]) 

        return wrapper

    return decorator

# And then later, something Flasky like:
@app.route("/things/:thing_id/frobnicate", method=["POST"])
@with_thing()
def frobnicate_thing(thing: Thing) -> Tuple[str, int]:
    # Do stuff with the thing...
    return "Thing was frobnicated.", 200
```

I've looked at https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypedDict and options like `total=False` don't seem like what I want, since I want the `thing_id` key to be required.

FWIW, I could probably achieve the typing I want in TypeScript like this:

```js
type IncomingKwargs = {
  thing_id: str,
  [key: str]: any,
}

const someKwargs: IncomingKwargs = {thing_id: "12345", description: "A beautiful thing",}

// Now `thing_id` is a string and `rest` is an object/dict of the other things. 
const { thing_id, ...rest } = someKwargs
```

Things I've tried:

- Reading docs, Python official and mypy - didn't find helpful examples
- Subclassing my `TypedDict` class with one that inherits both the `TypedDict` and a regular dict - didn't "compile", nor gave me a way to pass along the "rest"

Comment: This seems very much like an XY Problem. What problem are you trying to solve with these data structures exactly? It seems like classes and inheritance or something far simpler are better solutions.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what the X and the Y are? I would like to define data types such that I get thorough typechecking. Say someone updates the endpoint function (in this case "frobnicate_thing") to accept a "Widget" instead of a "Thing", I would like my typechecker (mypy) to flag that the decorator is incompatible now.

Comment: An 'XY problem' is a situation where someone is asking about issues with a specific solution, while the solution is not really suited to the actual problem they are trying to solve. Like asking someone about a problem you're having with trying to get a nail into a wall with a screwdriver. What is the actual problem or use case you are looking for a solution to? You suggest the vague "I have an endpoint that accepts a `Thing`, but what if someone changes the endpoint to accept a `Widget`?" and you illustrate this with some code-y stuff that you admit isn't real code. What's the actual problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python typing: Does TypedDict allow additional / extra keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71814658/python-typing-does-typeddict-allow-additional-extra-keys)

Comment: @Grismar Allow me to put some words in your mouth. The X (specific solution) is using a `TypedDict` with some values specified but allow for arbitrary additional ones; the Y (the actual problem) is that I want strong type checking on a decorator that will have some known kwargs and some arbitrary ones. Sure, this may be XYish, but given that kwargs is typed by a dict, a `TypedDict` seems like an appropriate tool to try to solve the problem with. Yes, my example isn't correct code _because_ I don't know the correct code, hence the question. You are free to offer a _different_ X if applicable.

Comment: @SUTerliakov It doesn't quite. That answer states that `TypedDict` doesn't guard against runtime addition of the keys (very true). But it doesn't explain how to access those extra keys in a typesafe way, and also not in a convenient way like the TS example I put would allow. I am about to try @l0b0's answer below to see if it works though.

Comment: If you know the content of the "bag of extra things", it can be done,

Comment: @hussic Do you mean that I would nest another `TypedDict` or something? I'm curious what you are getting at, but also want to clarify that in this particular use case (a decorator) you probably shouldn't assume anything about the other possible kwargs.

Comment: @t-r0d See my answer for an example.

Answer (score 3):

The thing you can do with TypeDict is to mix `total` and not `total` fields with inheritance:

```
class Movie(TypedDict, total=True):
    name: str

class Movie2(Movie, total=False):
    year: int  # optional
    rating: int  # optional

x: Movie2
x = {'name': 'a'}  # mypy ok
x = {'name': 'a', 'year': 3}  # mypy ok
x = {'name': 'a', 'year': 3, 'rating': 6}  # mypy ok
x = {'year': 3, 'rating': 6}  # mypy error: Missing key "name"
```

But this does not permit arbitrary fields.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! Hopefully this is helpful for others even if not directly useful for my decorator use case.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand this correctly, you want a kwargs type which specifies that the kwargs *must* contain some "thing" with a specific type, but can also contain other things. The easiest way I can think of doing this is to actually avoid `TypedDict`, and instead specify the known types directly:

```
def wrapper(*args: Any, thing_id: str, **kwargs: Any) -> R
```

Comment: You understand my problem correctly. Unfortunately I don't think this is a viable solution typechecking-wise (I'll bet it still works runtime-wise).

Applying this solution introduces a mypy error around the return value of `wrapper` and a Pylance error around parameter type of `wrapper`. Adding `# type: ignore[...]` to either error destroys the type strictness of the decoration. This was the most helpful thing I've come across so far though.