# How do I specify multiple TypedDict overloads in Python?

Tags: python, mypy

I'm trying to make a program which downloads minecraft mods and installs them in a folder. I'm currently working on making the types more strict so it's easier to debug my code. I now need to specify multiple 'overloads' for my TypedDict, like such:

```
from typing import Literal, TypedDict

class _MediaList(TypedDict, total=False):
    sides: list[Literal['client', 'server']]

class MediaList(TypedDict):
    type: Literal['cf', 'pm', 'mr', 'url']
    slug: str
    name: str


class MediaList(TypedDict):
    type: Literal['cf']
    id: int


class MediaList(TypedDict):
    type: Literal['pm']
    media: str


class MediaList(TypedDict):
    type: Literal['mr']
    id: int


class MediaList(TypedDict):
    type: Literal['url']
    link: str
```

How can I do this? If I [add `total=false`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76239973/is-there-a-way-to-specify-arbitrary-extras-in-a-python-typeddict) to some keys, I'd get type errors when I try to access the object (I know it's possible to workaround them, by checking which type it is before using it, but that's a poor way of doing this): `Could not access item in TypedDict. (item) is not a required key in "MediaList", so access may result in runtime exception (PylancereportTypedDictNotRequiredAccess)`, when it's defined like this:

```
from typing import Literal, TypedDict

class _MediaList(TypedDict):
    type: Literal['cf', 'pm', 'mr', 'url']
    slug: str
    name: str


class MediaList(_MediaList, total=False):
    id: int
    sides: list[Side]
    link: str
    sides: list[Literal['client', 'server']]
```

If you need an example of an MediaList dictionary, here some:

```json
{
    "type": "cf",
    "slug": "vanilla-zoom",
    "name": "vanillazoom-1.20.1-2.1.jar",
    "id": 4583468,
    "sides": [
        "client"
    ]
},
{
    "type": "mr",
    "slug": "fastload",
    "name": "Fastload-Reforged-8.2.1%2B1.20%28.1%29.jar",
    "id": "kCpssoSbHDvAnQIw"
},
{
    "type": "url",
    "slug": "essential",
    "name": "Essential-forge_1-20-1.jar",
    "link": "https://cdn.essential.gg/mods/60ecf53d6b26c76a26d49e5b/649c45fb8b045520b2c1c8b2/Essential-forge_1-20-1.jar",
},
{
    "type": "pm",
    "slug": "xxvi-s-better-cauldrons",
    "name": "better-cauldrons.zip",
    "media": "texture"
},
```

Comment: It's not about overloads (which exist only for functions), but about a simple union type. You can try something like [this](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.11&flags=strict&gist=15a3bfad90348ae261d4944313fbe42e).

Comment: Yeah I figured that out yesterday, but thanks anyway :)

Comment: @STerliakov I also saw you were using typing.Generic (haven't used that before) but I have a __NtMediaList(TypedDict, total=True) class and a _MediaList(__NtMediaList, total=False) class, where I put the non-required values. I wouldn't know how to do that with a Generic type

Comment: First, you don't really need totality flag in most cases - uses `typing.NotRequired` instead (or its backport to older versions from `typing_extensions`). However, you can use this metaclass argument the same way as you did before, `Generic` does not prevent such usage.